# How to quantify the relevant value change

Tags: quantify

I have two lists of values:

```
accuracy: 0.6, 0.6, 0.6
hit: 1, 1, 1
```

Now after some processing, these two lists of values become:

```
accuracy: 0.59, 0.58, 0.55
hit: 0.5, 0.3, 0.1
```

so the drop can be calculated as:

```
accuracy_drop: 0.01, 0.02, 0.05
hit_drop: 0.5, 0.8, 0.9
```

In my case, the third case with accuracy_drop = 0.05 and hit_drop = 0.9 is the optimal and I want to quantify this 'optimal' case by doing some calculation using the values I have. If calculating the hit_drop/accuracy_drop, the first case gives the highest value; if calculating the hit_drop-accuracy_drop, the third case gives the highest value but I am not sure whether this is a reasonable quantification.

I tried to search for some quantification methods of relevant value change but found nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Why is the third case optimal? You are describing a 2 dimensional space, so the 3rd case is a point in that space. You can calculate the distance between points, so you could quantify points based on their distance from "optimal".

Comment: Well, in my scenario, the third case is the best. Thanks for your idea!